# C++: Array and shared memory

Tags: c++, arrays, shared-memory

I am trying to create a piece of shared memory in order to share an array, here is my example:

```
int main(){
    key_t key;
    int shm_id;
    int arr[10];

    key=ftok("~/.bashrc",1);

    shm_id = shmget(key, 10*sizeof(int), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    arr = (int*)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);

    arr[0]=101;
    printf("%d\n",arr[0]);


}
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [10]’
```

What is wrong in my assignment?

Comment: It's better to create variables directly when you need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
int arr[10];
```

and change the call to shmat() to:

```
int* arr = (int*)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
```

A pointer variable can be used as an array, so `arr[0]=101` will still work.

(As @Andrew commented, its better to declare variables at the point where they are first used. This reduces the risk of using an uninitialised variable.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but if I follow your advice I get Segmentation fault. Note: I am compiling like this "g++ test.cpp -o testCPP"

Comment: At least it compiles now :)   The most likely reason for the segfault is that shmat() is returning null doe to an error. Check that ftok() and/or shmget() aren't returning -1 (indicating an error). If they are then check the value of errno for a clue about whats going wrong.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you are creating an IPC key for ~/.bashrc. You might want to try using a different (new) file. The shell might have some kind of lock on that file.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was basically shmget() returning -1 when I was trying to run the program again with the same settings, I guess because the memory was already allocated. ftok() was also returning -1 with the setting I showed but chanting "~/.bashrc" to "/home/username/.bashrc" solved the issue (although I do not understand very well why).

EDIT: OK, I'll take another file :)

Answer (score 7):

You should declare `arr` as a pointer, not as array:

```
int* arr;
```

You can't assign a pointer to array and `shmat()` returns a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

When you write arr[10] you allocate an array of elements on the stack. Implicitly this means that the value of &arr[0] (which is indeed a pointer to the first element in arr), can not be altered. If you want to copy the contents of shmat into the array arr you need to use `memcpy()` or some similar method to set the contents of arr properly.

Comment: shmat is a unix system function that attaches shared memory. It doesn't copy anything. The OP is trying to treat the shared memory as an array - a legitimate technique.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not understand 100% your suggestion. The thing is that I want to have an array which is placed in the shared memory so that its elements can be accessed / modified by different processes.

Comment: @Andy: Well I was just trying to explain the important difference between arr[] and * arr declarations, which I thought was the root of the misunderstanding here. I was not suggesting that shmat copies anything and I am not sure why you would want to copy something in shared memory to the stack variable, but still if you want the content of the memory location returned by shmat() in the stack array - you can use memcpy().